# [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Argument 1 of Range.setStart does not implement interface Node."

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to store `anchorNode` and `focusNode` to class object for future restoring of text selection.

I have this methods in my class:

```
saveSelection(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    
    this.selection.anchorNode = Object.assign({}, this.selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorNode);
    this.selection.focusNode = Object.assign({}, this.selection.focusNode, selection.focusNode);
    
    var newSelection = {
        anchorOffset: selection.anchorOffset, 
        focusOffset: selection.focusOffset,
        isCollapsed: selection.isCollapsed,             
    };
    
    this.selection = Object.assign({}, this.selection, newSelection);
}

placeCaretToPrevPosition(){
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range     = document.createRange();
    
    range.setStart(this.selection.anchorNode, this.selection.anchorOffset);
    range.setEnd(this.selection.focusNode, this.selection.focusOffset)
    range.collapse(this.selection.isCollapsed);
    
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

At some point I call `saveSelection()`. Later I call `placeCaretToPrevPosition()` but I get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Argument 1 of
> Range.setStart does not implement interface Node."

I use `Object.assign({},` because I use vue and want to preserve reactivity (according to this docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects ). I don't use `Vue.set()` because methods above is used as part of external class which is used within vue components, so I don't want to tie Vue to external classes. How to resolve this issue?

**PS.**

`this.selection.anchorNode` doesn't implement interface Node because I use `Object.assign({},`.